# Issue with npm jquery.alphanum used on Zurb Template Foundation 6 (jQuery not defined)

Tags: jquery, node.js, npm, zurb-foundation-6

I am having an issue trying to use the jQuery plugin [jquery.alphanum](https://github.com/KevinSheedy/jquery.alphanum) with Foundation 6.4.3 Zurb Template.

I am able to add most npm packages to my project `via npm instal [packagename]` and then including them in my app.js by (eg) `import swal from 'sweetalert2';`

However with jquery.alphanum, no matter how I add it to my project I always get the same error message on the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

I have tried adding it through npm, through copying the jquery.alphanum.js file into my src archives and linking it through a `<script>` tag, linking it through the cloudflare CDN and I always get the same error.

I through there might be some bug inside the alphanum js, so I tried making a simple index.html file outside of my project linking to jQuery and alphanum CDNs, and it works. It also works with a downloaded copy oof both jQuery and alpahnum.

Lastly, if i link to jQuery CDN and alphanum CDN or local AFTER my app.js it works.

I am a little stumped here...

On console, jQuery is actually defined as `jQuery331058191784730210581`

and the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>   at Object._typeof (app.js:22584)
>   at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>   at Object.defineProperty.value (app.js:14577)
>   at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>   at Object. (app.js:23159)
>   at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>   at _typeof (app.js:66)
>   at app.js:69

[Here is a link to a GitHub repo with the brand new Foundation project with only jquery.alphanum added.](https://github.com/kid-three/testgrounds)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. It has to do with changes from Foundation 6.3 to 6.3.

[The full answer is written by Urs Bram in the Foundation forums](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/53526#comment_42332)

The issue was modules that rely on global variables like $ or this being the window object. Changes in Foundation 6.4 messed with how some plugins are loaded.

[Imports Loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/imports-loader) has to be added to your project and the corresponding JS plugin that was not working. Then it can be imported like so:

`require("imports-loader?$=jquery!./example.js");`

Then a small change on your gulfile.babel.js file:

```
let webpackConfig = {
  resolve: {
alias: {
    jquery: "jquery/src/jquery"
  }
 },
  module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /.js$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
]}};
```

Hopefully this helps someone.